# PHP not reading one image data but Javascript is

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using PHPto store images and in most images it works perfectly but I have found some pictures that PHP isn't able to get its size or type but strangely Javascript is able to get this data:

> lastModified:1507536418411 lastModifiedDate:Mon Oct 09 2017 09:06:58
>
> GMT+0100 (Hora de Verão de GMT) name:"DSCF9495.jpg" size:3395678
>
> type:"image/jpeg"

But PHP gets the following:

> name: DSCF9495.jpg
>
> type: ""
>
> error: 1
>
> size: 0

My code is:

Index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="inputImage.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="value"><br><br>
        <input type="file" id="file" name="logo"><br><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var file = document.getElementById("file");
        file.addEventListener("change" , function(){
            console.log(file.files);    
        })
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

inputImage.php

```
<?php

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_FILES);
```

This looks to me like a problem with the image since only 4 images that came from the same camera have this problem, any other image I use works, even other jpg images.

Comment: It would be better, if you could post some code that you have written to do this.

Comment: It does tell you that there is one error. You might want to see what the error is.

Comment: Pls add code and elaborate your question (scenario)

Comment: Take a look at [mcve] to see how to ask here ;)

Comment: @Veve Thank you for formating my question correctly i will do my best to format my next questions correctly and to follow this website's rules more.

Comment: No problem, glad to see you're taking it well :)